# Getting rid of an unwanted /boot entry

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I recently attempted to get a dual-boot system running by installing Windows as an addendum to my existing Ubuntu install. I chose to install Windows on my second hard drive (HDD) rather than using up space on the SSD (where Ubuntu is installed), and at one stage during the process made the fatal mistake of attempting the install with the SSD still plugged in. Windows then proceeded to try and install itself, but rather than sticking to the HDD it installed its boot manager to the SSD's existing EFI partition, which caused no end of havoc with the install process until I finally came to my senses and disconnected the SSD.

The install worked this time and Windows is now working fine on the other drive. At the moment, I can only boot into it by going into the motherboard UEFI/BIOS menu and changing my boot order, so I'm now preparing to try and set up grub to handle the dual-boot. However, when I use `sudo os-prober` in the terminal, I get two windows entries: one for the real install on the HDD, and one for the 'dummy' boot manager on the SSD:

```
/dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi
/dev/sdb3@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows1:efi
```

(sda1 is the SSD EFI partition, sdb3 is Windows on the hard drive)

This isn't the end of the world (everything still works and the extra boot manager isn't taking up much space), but it is somewhat ugly, and as an inexperienced Ubuntu user I'm a little nervous about messing around with grub with this red herring floating around. If I were to simply delete the boot/EFI/Microsoft folder on the SSD, is that going to cause any problems that I haven't thought of for the rest of the system? Or is it the kind of thing I should just learn to live with for fear of breaking something else?